# InvocationException occurred invoking method?

Tags: java

Here is my method for a right BST rotation:

```
/**
 * Performs right rotation on a node 
 * Reset tags redoPreorder, redoInorder, redoPostorder 
 * 
 * @param n
 */
public void rightRotate(Node<E> n)
{
    Node<E> left = n.getLeft();
    Node<E> parent = n.getParent();
    left.setParent(parent);
    parent.setLeft(left);
    n.setParent(left);
    if(left.getRight() != null){
        Node<E> right = left.getRight();
        n.setLeft(right);
        //n.setLeft(right);
        right.setParent(n);
        left.setRight(n);
    }
    else{
        left.setRight(n);
    }
    redoInorder = true;
    redoPostorder = true;
    redoPreorder = true;
}
```

And this is my node toString()

```
/**
 * Write the value of the instance variable named data.
 */
public String toString()
{
    String str = data + "";
    return str;
}
```

(in the tree below, 'n' is 4)
So I am going over a tree structured:

```
+7
 +4
  +3
   -2
   -
  -6
 +11
  -9
  +18
   +14
    -12
    -17
   +19
    -
    +22
     -20
     -
```

Note: + indicates the node has children, - means it is a leaf. For
+7
 -4
 -8
7 is root of tree/subtree, 4 is left child, and 8 is right child (this is not in my example but just to let you know how this notation works).

So my issue... When I hit

```
 else{ left.setRight(n); }
```

in my rotate method, eclipse gives me 
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.

I don't understand why. All other instances of my node setters have worked fine, And this error gives you no hints as to what is causing the trouble, so am seeing if someone more experienced than I might find something. I just don't see why that is causing a problem.

Thanks for any help.

Ok here is a failure trace for a right rotate test if that helps:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Integer.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at edu.iastate.cs228.hw5.BST.recursiveInorderTraversal(BST.java:363)
    at edu.iastate.cs228.hw5.BST.recursiveInorderTraversal(BST.java:359)
    at edu.iastate.cs228.hw5.BST.recursiveInorderTraversal(BST.java:359)
    at edu.iastate.cs228.hw5.BST.recursiveInorderTraversal(BST.java:366)
    at edu.iastate.cs228.hw5.BST.recursiveInorderTraversal(BST.java:359)
    at edu.iastate.cs228.hw5.BST.recursiveInorderTraversal(BST.java:366)
```

**The recursiveInorderTraversals go on for a while... but you get the gist lol.

I am thinking something is wrong with a toString()? It doesn't make sense that it gets stuck in a cycle like that, it didn't use to until I added that else{} statement, but I needed that because it wasn't properly rotating.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: I believe you will get that error if you have a cycle somewhere in your tree.  Are you using Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't share all the code so I'm going to take a guess.  If your node has data set to null, then your toString() method will fail.  I believe your IDE is throwing the exception because it is trying to call toString() to show you the object in the debugger.

Comment: Hmm that very well is probably my issue. But if a node only has one child, the other is null, but a rotate involves setting one of the children (possibly the null one) to another node... hmmm

Comment: Oh wait, no node has data set to null though, there simply is no node for the right child of 3, therefore it is a null space. So I don't get why using a set is causing this.

Comment: Could be similar issue though.  What does the code for setLeft() and setRight() do?  Are you null-checking?

Comment: No :P. All they did was set the right node to the specified one, which should work even if the node is null, it would just set it to an actual node. But I believe I found out the issue! In my else{} statement I needed to set one of n's child references to null because its parent was still its child as well. hahahaha Oh goodness.

Comment: There it is... you were creating an unintentional cycle which was my initial idea.  Congrats!